# Can't run any application with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I used to work with Intellij IDEA and at a certain moment something happened that i can't run any application anymore. The problem is that buttons 'Run' and 'Debug' (the ones that are called with Shift+F10 and Shift+F9) are inactive -

[image: Watch screenshot here].

There are also another pair of this buttons, that are called with Alt+Shift+F10(F9), but after i click on them, i get this -

[image: Screenshot].

I tried to reinstall IDE, but that didn't help. Here the code of the application i'm trying to run, though it doesn't work with any application.

P.S. I'd like to add also a screenshot of the project structure, but i can't post more that 2 links, so i just do this way:

```
>untitled
  >idea
  >out
  >src
    >(C) WallyFinder
  untitled1.iml
>External Libraries
```

The code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class WallyFinder {

    public static int wheresWally(String str) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(" Wally\\b").matcher(" " + str);
        return m.find() ? m.start() : -1;
    }

public static void main(String args){
    int a = WallyFinder.wheresWally("aaaaWally");
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

Comment: *public static void main(String args)* should be *public static void main(String[] args)*

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure is wrong I think. It should be like this

```
>untitled
  >idea
  >out
  >src
    >main
       >java
         >(C) WallyFinder
  untitled1.iml
>External Libraries
```

Can you please try this.

Comment: Thanks fo advice, but the problem wasn't that actually. Changing main(String args) to main(Strng[] args) helped.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that but an answer was already made. But you should follow this structure as it will help you in many ways.